# Appending Python Dictionaries to a List

Tags: python, graphql

I am attempting to iterate through the output of a GraphQL query as JSON and create a list of Python dicts (the 'projects' variable) containing the information. Here is the code I have been using so far:

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/graphql'
api_token = 'API_TOKEN'
headers = {'Authorization': 'token %s' % api_token}

# Parse Output
r = requests.post(url=url, json={'query': query}, headers=headers)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
df_data = json_data['data']['user']['pinnedItems']['edges']
data = df_data
i = 0
while i < len(df_data):
    for key, value in df_data[i].items():
        projects = [
            {
                'name': value['name'],
                'url': value['url']
            }
        ]

    i += 1
```

However, when I execute this code and print out `projects`, only the first object is captured. Does anyone have any idea how to get more than one object to be added to the list? I have four objects in total.

Note: The JSON is based on GraphQL output from the GitHub API, the query is below:

```
query {
    user(login:"USER") {
    pinnedItems(first: 4, types: [REPOSITORY]) {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on Repository {
            name
            shortDescriptionHTML
            url
            openGraphImageUrl
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the full JSON output from GitHub:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "pinnedItems": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "TEXT",
              "shortDescriptionHTML": "TEXT",
              "url": "URL",
              "openGraphImageUrl": "URL"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "TEXT",
              "shortDescriptionHTML": "TEXT",
              "url": "URL",
              "openGraphImageUrl": "URL"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "TEXT",
              "shortDescriptionHTML": "TEXT",
              "url": "URL",
              "openGraphImageUrl": "URL"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "name": "TEXT",
              "shortDescriptionHTML": "TEXT",
              "url": "URL",
              "openGraphImageUrl": "URL"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You were basically creating every time a new list with one item.
To append more items to the same list, you need to use the method "list.append()", as python_guy_rany has shown to you.

However, if you want to keep using the while loop, do not forget to add the i+=1 to the python_guy_rany code.
I'd rather use a for loop:

```
for i in range(len(df_data)):
```

you can avoid both i=0 and i+=1 with this.
You could also use a list comprehension, but I think sticking with the for loop it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
while i < len(df_data):
    for key, value in df_data[i].items():
        projects = [
            {
            'name': value['name'],
            'url': value['url']
            }
        ]
```

To this:

```
   data = []    
    while i < len(df_data):
        for key, value in df_data[i].items():
            tmp_data = {'name': value['name'], 'url': value['ur']}
            data.append(tmp_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

> only the first object is captured

You are not capturing the first data. The list is being overwritten node after node. So what you are seeing is actually the information of the **last node**. It is good practice to name your sample data differently, like numbering them for example, easier to troubleshoot.

What is the use of `data = df_data`, it is being initialized but not used.

```py
df_data = json_data['data']['user']['pinnedItems']['edges']
data_length = len(df_data)
i = 0
projects = []
while i < data_length:
    for key, value in df_data[i].items():
        node_data = [{'name': value['name'], 'url': value['url']}]
        projects.append(node_data)
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
[[{'name': 'TEXT1', 'url': 'URL'}], [{'name': 'TEXT2', 'url': 'URL'}], [{'name': 'TEXT3', 'url': 'URL'}], [{'name': 'TEXT4', 'url': 'URL'}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_data['data']['user']['pinnedItems']['edges']` is a list of dictionaries so it would be very easy to parse it using a list comprehension.

```py
url = 'https://api.github.com/graphql'
api_token = 'API_TOKEN'
headers = {'Authorization': 'token %s' % api_token}

# Parse Output
r = requests.post(url=url, json={'query': query}, headers=headers)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
df_data = json_data['data']['user']['pinnedItems']['edges']

data = [{'name':x['node']['name'], 'url':x['node']['url']} for x in df_data]
```